# Should I deploy as an ADF Library Jar to call functions?

Tags: java, oracle, jar, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Currently I am using JDeveloper 12c to develop a project in oracle ADF.

My problem is when I deployed the XmlGenerator project as a JAR file and added in the XmlGeneratorApp project View>Project Properties>Libraries and ClassPath>Adf Library it should let me use the functions in the JAR file but it isn't.

I added a similar one as an ADF Library JAR file called CustomComponent it worked very well when I called the functions implemented in the classes from it.

My question is it mandatory to deploy it as ADF Library JAR file to use its functions? If not, and a JAR file is only necessary what should I do to call the functions in the JAR file because I can't deploy the XmlGenerator project as an ADF Library Jar file which is weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I hope my answer to myself will help anyone using oracle adf. Here are few steps:

1-Deploy your application as a jar by right clicking on the view > new deployment profile

2-If you can't deploy it as an ADF JAR Library you should deploy as JAR (my problem)

3-After creating the new deployment profile you should deploy it

4-To add it to another project so you can use the methods in the public classes you should right click in the view and the model of the project you want to add then add it to:
 Project Properties>Libraries and ClassPath> ADF Library>Edit>Add Entry

That should do it. Hope this was helpful and very clear.

N.B: If you could deploy it as an ADF JAR Library you could simply add it by right-clicking on it in the IDE Connections and select the project and right-clicking on the jar to add it directly to the project.